# Close a div when clicked anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html

I have a search box that selects users and sends them into a div on my page which obviously opens with the script. But I would like the box to close if the user clicks outside of the div anywhere on my sites page. I've played around with a few ideas but haven't got what I'm looking for.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="search_txt" placeholder="Search for friends" class="blog_input_field" onKeyUp="dosearch(document.getElementById('search_txt').value,'ajaxsearch_results');"><hr>
<div class="searchresults" id="ajaxsearch_results">
```

**REQUEST FUNCTION**

```
function dosearch(text,containerid){
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();

    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4) {
            //alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
            document.getElementById(containerid).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","include/search.people.php?t="+text,true);
    xmlhttp.send();

}
```

Comment: The above code is giving me the same problem I was having. When I click inside the search its not showing any results and hiding the top of my page.

Comment: I have posted the code below please check that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In jquery You can do something like this:

```
$(document).click(function(){
   $('.searchresults').hide();   
});

$('.searchresults').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

​

Comment: Fantastic. Works just as I needed it to. Simple, yet effective. Will accept shortly. Thank you

Comment: Can I also ask another question as it relates to this post. Once the window closes and I try searching again..I can't search it doesn't show unless I refresh the page. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: which window? you mean browser ?
Could you elaborate ?

Comment: Sorry. The div. Once I click out and I try to search for another user it doesn't display any results. I can only display new results when I refresh the page. Is this a cache problem?

Comment: Ok.  As per the requirement you mentioned before you want to hide the div when user clicks on any other place other than that specific div.  So when you try searching for new user, it wont display that div because its hidden, You need to do remove hide.. $('.searchresults').show().

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15788/discussion-between-aby-and-dave)

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with raw JS, no need for Jquery. You hook the onmousedown or on click, and take advantage of the fact that JS events bubble up, eventually (unless blocked) to the document. So:

```
document.onmousedown (or onclick) = function (e) {

  if (!e) e = window.event; // for browser compatibility

  target = (e.target ) ? e.target : e.srcElement; // again for browser compat..

  // note - could be child of div, too: see fine print    
  if (e.target.id != "divIDgoesHere")
      document.getElementById('divIDgoesHere').style.display = "none" ;
      // or other hide
}
```

The fine print:

- if you click inside the div, the target might be some inner child of the div. In which case, you can iterate over parentNode till you get to the search div, and ignore those requests.
- you could also remove the div altogether (div.parentNode.removeChild(div)).
- you'll need to tweak the code some. Nothing major.

Hope this helps

TG